# Добавить элемент с помощью JS в зависимости от select

Tags: javascript, select

Доброго времени суток.
Нужно чтобы в зависимости от выбранного `select` после следующего поля `input` добавлялся текст.
Например: если выбрал в `select` `Россия`, то после `input` добавлялся `руб`, выбрал `США` - добавлялся `долл` и т. д.

Есть код, но он, как Вы понимаете, не работает:

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function createText() {
  var selectValue = document.getElementById("money").value;
  var CashInput = document.getElementById("cash");
  var temp = document.createElement("p");
  if (selectValue == "rub") {
    var text = "rub";
    temp.appendChild(text);
    insertAfter(CashInput, temp);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="money" onchange="createText();">
  <option value="rub">Russia</option>
  <option value="doll">USA</option>
</select>

<input id="cash">
```

Comment: и как именно он не работает?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Забудьте уже DOM Event Level 0 Inline! Т.е. вставку обработчиков в HTML - onclick='бла-бла-бла'
let data = {
  id: {
    SELECT: '#money',
    INPUT:  '#cash',
    PRICE:  '#price',
    SIGN:   '#sign'
  },
  value: {
    rub: "руб",
    usd: '$'
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { // Ждём загрузки DOM, чтобы найти элементы
  let select = document.querySelector(data.id.SELECT),
      input  = document.querySelector(data.id.INPUT);
  
  select.addEventListener('change', signHandler);
  input.addEventListener('keyup', priceHandler);
  
  signHandler.call(select); //  Сразу выберем знак
  priceHandler.call(input); //  И значение
});

function signHandler(){
  document.querySelector(data.id.SIGN).textContent = data.value[this.selectedOptions[0].value];
}

function priceHandler(){
  let price = this.value === '' ? '0' : this.value;
  document.querySelector(data.id.PRICE).textContent = price;
}
```

```html
<select id="money">
  <option value="rub">Russia</option>
  <option value="usd">USA</option>
</select>

<input id="cash" value='0'><br />
<span><span id='price'></span> <span id='sign'></span</span>
```

А не работает Ваш код из-за того, что `appendChild` принимает только `Node`, а передаётся строка.

Comment: Извините, возможно я чего-то не понимаю,
но inline обработчики разгружают страницу, по такому принципу работает VK,часть Yandex приложений, в фейсбуке висят несколько обработчиков и в зависимости от data-атрибутов у target-y выполняются различные действия, то есть все пытаются разгрузить количество events  на странице. и к примеру до сегодняшнего времени 100% способ отследить что картинка не подгрузилась это записать inline onerror.

Comment: @sivik_xes Они есть исключительно из-за того, что это самый первый способ реализации Наблюдателя (т. е. вышеуказанные сайты просто хотят чтобы у них древние IE работали и побольше народу было. Или же просто их код писался в древности, когда это был единственный способ, а сейчас их банально никто не обновляет (хотя стоило бы)). Плюсов по сравнению с новыми `addEventListener` у них нет. Ну разве что посмотрел в HTML и увидел сразу все обработчики. Но смешивать HTML и JS - идея так себе. И да - inline способ стар и ничего не разгружает, новый способ пооптимизированнее будет.

Comment: Ну в плане оптимизации я имею ввиду, что изначально после загрузки страницы addEventListener записывает обработчики которые висят постоянно, не имеет значения пользователь совершил действие или нет, каждый раз проверяется не по тому ли элементу произошло действие, а инлайн обработчики инициализируются непосредственно при самом действии, и не висят в памяти. единственное чем хорош addEventListener - что ты можешь на 1 и тот же элемент навесить несколько однотипных обработчиков.
к стати https://new.vk.com/blog работает по тому-же принципу.

Comment: Не могу запустить Ваш код, даже здесь

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, как он работает,

Comment: @WiAim, какой браузер и его версию используешь для запуска? Старые браузеры этот код не поддерживают (т.е. те, которым место в музее). Хром давно поддерживает. Как работает: После загрузки страницы, находим и вешаем обработчики на `select` и `input`. При изменении первого, получаем выделенный элемент `this.selectedOptions[0]`, берём его `value` и используем как ключ в объекте `data.value`, где хранятся литералы валют ('руб', '$', etc) и вставляем значение в `#sign`. А `keyup` - просто для наглядности, берёт введённое значение и вставляет в `#price`.

Comment: Вы правы, не работало из за браузера(Firefox)
После изменения нескольких строк и мой заработал, спасибо вам большое.
И еще вопрос, почему не желательно пользоваться обработчиками?

Comment: @WiAim, рад что работает, просто я использовал новинки ECMA, которые очень уж удобны и решают кучу наболевших проблем. Если нужно перевести такой код в старый, то юзай это: http://babeljs.io/repl/ Обработчиками можно и нужно пользоваться. Просто есть те, которые пишутся в HTML (`<input onClick='some(this)' />`), а есть которые вешают через `addEventListener`. Первые существовали с самого начала и давно устарели (ибо DOM Event 0), а вешать через функцию - безопасно и удобно. Тут описано про это: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/comparison

Answer (score -2):

Реализация с JQuery

Добавил пример реализации без jquery так как автору это принципиально

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="money" onchange="$('.info-div').text($(this).val());">
    <option value="rub">Russia</option>
    <option value="doll">USA</option>
</select>

<input id="cash">
<div class="info-div" style="display:inline-block">rub</div>

<hr>

<select id="money" onchange="document.querySelector('.info-div-no-jquery').innerHTML = this.value;">
    <option value="rub">Russia</option>
    <option value="doll">USA</option>
</select>

<input id="cash">
<div class="info-div-no-jquery" style="display:inline-block">rub</div>
```

Comment: а где вы нашли упоминание jQuery в вопросе или метках к нему?

Comment: я так понмаю это принципиально? без  jquery?

Comment: Да, сейчас нужен именно он